# how to run function in react native once per installation

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

### App Explain

I'm developing react native reminder app and I want to call a function that reminds time of the day
want to call the function once per installation and never call it again when user open the app. just once per installation

using
react-native-push-notification
PouchDb

try asyncStorage but it's not good solution for this case

### function##

```
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
      id:notificationId,
      message: reminder.name, // (required)
      date: new Date(Date.now() + diffSeconds), 
      allowWhileIdle: true,
      repeatType:"week",
      channelId : "Reminder",
      priority:"max",
      largeIcon : "logo", 
      soundName: "remind",
      smallIcon : ""
    })
```

Comment: Why is `asyncstorage` not useful in this scenario ?

Comment: because asyncStorage called many time in app and if i use more asyncStorage app becomes slow i try to find some good solution to handle this

Comment: What if you have a key value pair called `isNotified` in async storage. You can add a `componentDidMount` / `useEffect (with empty [])` in your main App.js/ts file and check `isNotifiedValue` from async storage. If the value is false, you can do your necessary logic to send the notification and set the `isNotified` value to true. This way you can ensure that the check only happens once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your state management tool, such as Redux. Basically, you want to initialize state, for example, **isOnboardingDone** which will be false in the beginning, and you will set it to true after your function is called. However, you need to save the state in the AsyncStorage after, or in other words, you need to persist it. The alternative to AsyncStorage would be to create a field in one of your database tables, such as profile, and to change it via API call.

Answer (score 0):

There's no perfect solution to this problem.

I usually solve this by canceling the previously scheduled notification and then registering a new one each time on app startup. This ensures that there's only one scheduled notification with the same ID

```
await PushNotification.cancelLocalNotification('123');

await PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
  id:'123',
  ...
})
```

Comment: thsnks for feedBack i try this before but user can change the pushnotification time and date this solution  make same notification with the same time i used pouchdb to save notifications time and setting .there is not a solution for that in react native

Comment: In cases, you need to change the date/time you can call `getScheduledLocalNotifications` to get a list of scheduled notifications. 
Find your notification by the hard-coded ID. Get the current date/time of the notification. Now you have the data to show to the user, and you can allow him to change it after which you schedule the new notification.